# (Undergrad looking for help) In logarithmic regression (log-log), what does it mean if your explanatory variable is already a percentage?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, econometrics, macroeconomics

So I'm hoping to a regression of Human Development Index against some economic variables I think could affect it. Some types of aid per capita, education spending by government as a percentage of gdp, the actual gdp per capita and finally the % of the population with water access.

Now, for all the variables but the last one, I was fine thinking I would just make them logs along with HDI, as I would want to know the percentage change in HDI caused by a % change in x. But with water access, it's already a percentage variable? Should I leave it as is, or log it anyway. If so, how do I interpret the result? Is it a percentage point change???

Sorry, I'm still new to regression!

Comment: Welcome. Do you mind if I ask why you’re log-transforming the percentages?

Comment: I wanted to have a log log model originally, I don't know if it's okay for some variables to be logs and others not to be.